# Endpoint returns blank page when going to path on Ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, amazon-eks

I have an endpoint with multiple paths, each path pointing to a different service, each different service pointing to a different deployment (hosting multiple different applications under the same url with different paths basically).

Whenever I go to the path in the browser, I am met with a blank page. The main root path works fine, but none of the paths after that work. I have been able to route through using kubectl proxy and can confirm the container works fine, so it has to be with the ingress pathing. Here is my spec object:

```
 20 spec:
 21   rules:
 22   - host: redacted.co.uk
 23     http:
 24       paths:
 25       - backend:
 26           serviceName: redacted-svc
 27           servicePort: 80
 28       - backend:
 29           serviceName: redacted-svc-1
 30           servicePort: 80
 31         path: /redacted1
 32       - backend:
 33           serviceName: redacted-svc-2
 34           servicePort: 80
 35         path: /redacted2
```

any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Are you also meaning to strip `/redacted1` from the request before it's sent to the service?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: traefik has a stripprefix middleware. Can't say exactly because I'm still using an older version of traefik before it introduced middlewares. Prior to that it was done via a stripprefix annotation.

Comment: do you mean ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /?

Comment: `traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip`, but again, it's different in traefik 2.x.

Comment: Here is 2.x docs: https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/stripprefix/

Comment: Still having trouble with this, tried the path stripping to no effect :(